# Exeception " Operation not permitted on IsolatedStorageFileStream."

Tags: windows-phone-7

I am trying to save a Image from IsolatedStorage.I got an error: "Operation not permitted on IsolatedStorageFileStream.". My code shown below. How can I overcome this problem?

```
  public HomePage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            // Create a filename for JPEG file in isolated storage.
            String tempJPEG = "/Images/homescreenmap.png";

            // Create virtual store and file stream. Check for duplicate tempJPEG files.
            using (IsolatedStorageFile myIsolatedStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
            {
                if (myIsolatedStorage.FileExists(tempJPEG))
                {
                    myIsolatedStorage.DeleteFile(tempJPEG);
                }

                IsolatedStorageFileStream fileStream = myIsolatedStorage.CreateFile(tempJPEG);

                StreamResourceInfo sri = null;
                Uri uri = new Uri(tempJPEG, UriKind.Relative);
                sri = Application.GetResourceStream(uri);

                BitmapImage bitmap = new BitmapImage();
                bitmap.SetSource(sri.Stream);
                WriteableBitmap wb = new WriteableBitmap(bitmap);

                // Encode WriteableBitmap object to a JPEG stream.
                Extensions.SaveJpeg(wb, fileStream, wb.PixelWidth, wb.PixelHeight, 0, 85);

                //wb.SaveJpeg(fileStream, wb.PixelWidth, wb.PixelHeight, 0, 85);
                fileStream.Close();
            }


        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IsolatedStorageException means that it cannot find the path to location which you set, in your case this is folder Images. Just add before you create a file this code:

```
if (!myIsolatedStorage.DirectoryExists("Images"))
{
    myIsolatedStorage.CreateDirectory("Images");
}
```

Comment: :thank its working but new NullReffrenceException is generate.

Comment: in what line of code you get NullReferenceException? My guess that it can be in this line "bitmap.SetSource(sri.Stream);", because "sri = Application.GetResourceStream(uri);" returns null.